# MySQL best match for data including keywords

Tags: mysql, performance

There are two `name` columns in my table. (name1, name2)

I want to receive keywords as input and output them in the most similar order among the data including the keywords.

If the user inputs `ed`, we want the output to be in the order of 'ed', 'Ed Sheeran' and 'Ahmedzidan'.
(The order of 'Ed Sheeran' and 'Ahmed Zidan' may vary depending on the matching method.)

We want the word 'ed' to be the most similar and immediately followed by the word 'ed'.

I don't know how to do exact matching.

The above 'ed' is searched even if it is included in either name1 or name2.
There is no priority between the two.

The method I am using now:

```sql
select
    ((LENGTH(name1) - LENGTH(( 'ed')))) + ((LENGTH(name) - LENGTH(( 'ed')))
    ) as score
from user
where name like '%ed%' or name2 like '%ed%'
order by score asc
```

Another way:

```sql
select
    (CASE WHEN name1 = 'ed' or name2 = 'ed' THEN 4
        WHEN name1 like 'ed%' or name2 like 'ed%' THEN 3
        WHEN name1 like '%ed' or name2 like '%ed' THEN 2
        WHEN name1 like '%ed%' or name2 like '%ed%' THEN 1
        END
    )
    as score
from user
where name like '%ed%' or name2 like '%ed%'
order by score desc
```

However, both results are different from what I thought, and I don't know which one is faster.

I tried using a `full-text index`, but it seems to require too much sacrifice(?) to search for one alphabet.
And it was too slow when when the user was typing keywords in long words.

Example: keyword : ed -> 0.2s , keyword : ed Sheeran -> 5s.

What is the best way?

If the above two methods are the best, which one  could be faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me discuss the performance impact of each part of the query:

1. The `WHERE` has `OR` and `LIKE` with a leading wildcard.  Each of those forces the query to do a full scan, checking every row.
2. I don't need to discuss further; all other aspects (including the lengthy `CASE`) are less important in judging speed.  Things like `POSITION` vs the alternative might shave off 1%.

If the table is huge (and cannot be cached in RAM), then this would help some:  `INDEX(name1, name2)`  The trick here is to change a table scan into an index scan.

All work is done in the "buffer_pool" in RAM.  When a table is bigger than RAM, and the query needs to look at all the rows, the processing must bump things out of the buffer_pool to load data from disk.  I/O is likely to be the biggest factor in performance.

The table's BTree contains all the columns for all the rows.  The INDEX mentioned contains one row for each name1, name2 and whatever column(s) comprise the `PRIMARY KEY`.  That is, the index is likely to be smaller than the table.  Hence the index might sit in RAM, whereas the data would have to be page in.  (It's about I/O.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use POSITION function and order by it. There is no need such using select CASE becouse there is no such a logic oparation in your query and duplicate LIKE function, that to much wasteting time. With using POSTION function you can get the result like you want, if you just want to order "Ed Sharon" first than followed By other "ed" like "Mr. Bambang Ed".

```
SELECT name, POSITION('a' IN name) pos FROM user WHERE name LIKE '%a%' ORDER BY pos ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But in my case using POSITION is slower. TT